# NextJs: do have any problem by writing code for mongoose connection in next.config.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have been doing research for creating a standard connection for MongoDB using mongoose in React NextJs. But, in every blog, I saw that we need to write code for mongoose connection in a function and call it on every page.
[function for connect mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLDPH.png)

That was very disgusting. When I used express I can connect the DB in the index file and do every DB method in routes without re-calling it again.
Today, I saw configuring the required packages in next.config.js. So, I think writing mongoose connection in it will work. **And it works!**
[Mongoose connection in next.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naBe8.png)

But, I am afraid that no bloggers show that way of connecting. So, I doubt that writing a connection in it makes any bug or performance issue for the next app?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

from my point of vue i don't see any advantages to put it in next.config, in the official documentation, the way it to pass it through app.module.ts and store your mongo uri in a .env file to avoid exposing sensible crendentials.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_URI, {}),
    AuthModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```